# Load current user with Vue/Axios in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Okay I'm trying to find the best way to load the current user into my vue app so that I can pull the username and ID from any other component or route.

Right now I've tried this:

**app.js**

```
new Vue({

el: '#app',

computed: {
    user(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('/current-user')
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response.data);

                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error.response.data);
                });
        });
    }
},
router
});
```

It will log my user just fine, but I can't call `@{{ user }}` in any blade file. How exactly am I supposed to get the current user on app initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` computed property returns `Promise` object not desired value.

Below is my proposition of solving your problem. You should be able to succesfully call `@{{ user }}` within your blade files. However to access `user` property in children components you are forced to use `$parent.user` property of theirs.

Personally I recommend you checking out [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which is made for such cases. It is centralized state storing solution allowing you to access (and manage) data from all over your app.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      user: null
    };
  },
  created () {
    // As app intializes user is fetched and saved
    this.fetchUser();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUser () {
      axios.get('/current-user')
        .then(response => {
          this.user = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert('Something went wrong');
          console.error(error.response.data);
        });
    }
  },
  router
});
```